# aligning text and circles in css and html

Tags: html, css

Okay, so what I have so far looks something like this:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEt8y/1/)

```
.circleblue {
width: 1em;
height: 1em;
margin-left: 45%;
padding-top: -5%;
-webkit-border-radius:50%;
-moz-border-radius:50%;
background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.25, #3A547A),
    color-stop(0.60, #668EC9)
);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    #3A547A 25%,
    #668EC9 60%
);
border: solid 2px black;
float: right;
z-index: 100;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>Bla<p class="circleblue"></p><p class="circleblue"><p class="circleblue"></p></li>
<li>Blup<p class="circleblue"><p class="circleblue"><p class="circleblue"></li>
<li>Blop<p class="circleblue"><p class="circleblue"><p class="circleblue"></li>
</ul>
```

but that is not at all what I want. I know this should be pretty simple but I am having all sorts of trouble with it. I want the text first and then the circles representing my skill in this area like this:

bla * * *
blup * * *
blop * * *

where is that simple solution that I just cannot find?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LEt8y/5/ ... Also, you open a bunch of `<p>` tags for your circles, but never close them

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LEt8y/7/ This might be a start

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LEt8y/8/ or like that? http://jsfiddle.net/LEt8y/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the multiple declaration of the same class almost drove me crazy lol j/k I re-did your html and included your css as well.

[***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvDfL/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `span` instead of a `p`, for a start:

```html
<ul class="skills">
    <li>Bla
        <span class="blue-circle"></span>
        <span class="blue-circle"></span>
        <span class="blue-circle"></span>
    </li>
    <li>Blup
        <span class="blue-circle"></span>
        <span class="blue-circle"></span>
        <span class="blue-circle"></span>
    </li>
    <li>Blop
        <span class="blue-circle"></span>
        <span class="blue-circle"></span>
        <span class="blue-circle"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Next, there is no need to `float` the `span`s. You can use `display: inline-block` to enable you to keep the `span` inline and use the block CSS properties (e.g. `margin`, `padding`, `width` and `height`):

```css
.skills {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.skills > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;

    padding-right: 12px;
}

.skills > li > .blue-circle {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.25, #3A547A), color-stop(0.60, #668EC9));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #3A547A 25%, #668EC9 60%);

    border: solid 2px black;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    display: inline-block;

    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;

    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCLRS/10/) for a working example.